# Xamarin debugging not working properly

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I updated Xamarin iOS inside Visual Studio and debugging stopped working for portable libraries but it is working inside the iOS project.

However if I change the debugging from iPhoneSimulator to iPhone and vice versa the break points inside the pcl start working but if I change the code inside the pcl the break point will not hit anymore.

These are the versions I am using.
Xamarin   3.11.445.0
Xamarin.iOS   8.10.0.0
Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0.31101.00 update 4

It's kind of frustrating not being able to debug, spent the whole day trying to figure this out :s

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed in the latest Alpha & Beta releases, as detailed in the release discussion here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37275/alpha-release-xamarinvs-3-11-271-new-features-and-bug-fixes/p1

> "Bug 29628 - [XamarinVS] [iOS] Breakpoints in Portable Class Libraries do not work because the .mdb symbol files are not copied properly. Related warning in the 'Output -> Debug' window: 'Symbol file ... doesn't match image'. **Now fixed in the Beta and Alpha channels.**